# Remove System Tray Icons in Wm6.5

Tags: c++, windows-mobile-6.5

I want to to remove the volume system icon from the top bar of the command bar. I have been looking for a solution, but so far have found nothing. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: You are looking for a programmatic solution?

Comment: memset (&nid, 0, sizeof nid);
nid.cbSize = sizeof (NOTIFYICONDATA);
nid.hWnd = hWnd;//what handle the handle to the system shell?
nid.uID = ??????;//this field is unkown for me
Shell_NotifyIcon (NIM_DELETE, &nid);

Comment: Please add that information to your question, not to the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not remove the icon for volume, nor any other from the wm65 taskbar. These icons are defined by the OEM in the OS image build. You can change the app that is called when a user taps the loudspeaker in the ribbon bar popup. See my article about kiosk mode part2. regards, josef (www.hjgode.de/wp